# How to proper send messages via bluetooth from Android to Arduino continuously

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, send, outputstream

I have a goal to control some arduino device via BT with help of my android phone.
When I touch a screen and move my finger around, android app generate some data, depending on my finger position, forming a string message, and then trying to send it over BT.

The problem is, when the app attempts to send many many iterations of this command.

For example, the command is: String command = "[code]command(data)/";

When I just tap a time on a screen, the app write the command once and send it over BT, and it looks good on the other side (arduino).
But when I hold and move the finger, app trying to rewrite the command every "frame", and also trying to send this command every "frame" (I mean, every moment, many many times). And then I see something like: "[code]co[cod[co[c[mma(da]coode[c[co".

The feeling is... it gets one characters array and mixed it with another, when sending... or begin sending another message before stops sending previous.

Here is the code that gets some values on touch event:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initPosX = x;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // some code that make counts and convert values...

                // prepare string as a command.
                String command = "[code]command(" + value + ")/";
                Log.d("command", command);
                // send data via BT
                sendData(command);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //code
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Also I have BT settings up code, it all works good.

And this is the main part. Code that sending the string:

```
protected void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        try {
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //some exception code
        }

    }
```

`outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();`

So... I really don't know why this happens. I wasted entire day trying to search something about.
Will be very appreciated if someone can give me a glue, where to dig next.
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Arduino side code:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char c = Serial.read(); // read char from BT
    serialMessage.concat(c); // add this char to string.
    delay(5);

    if (c == '/') {
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print(serialMessage); // print message on a display.
      command = serialMessage;
      serialMessage = "";
    }
  }
  else {
    if (serialMessage != "") {
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print(serialMessage); // print message on a display.
      serialMessage = "";
    }
    //command = serialMessage;
    
  }
```

**UPDATE 2:**
This is a real Serial input, when I tap once

```
[code]command(0.0)/
```

and when I move finger left and right

```
[code]command(0.0)/
[code]command(0.0)/
[code]command(0.0)/
[code]command(0.23)/
[code]cm()dm()[c]a.[em1[(/
em1[em1[]a.cca.[e)[dm(/
dm(/
em1[em1[co0ood)dmd4ood8oon2ccn0cca0/
ccn.[]a-)dm(6oon.[]a1[]od0o0[c]a1[]a1[em-/
em-)dm()dm(0odcn.cca0a.[]a.[em0/
em0)dm()dm()dm(/
em1/
em1[]a1[]a.ccn0oon7ccn4c]a.ccn.[em-)dm()oodod0ccn.ccn.[]m-/
d0ooood0ccn.ccn.[]a1[]a-/
em-/
em(5ood7c]a0/
em-)ood0[em0)dm()dm(3od)dm(/
dm(/
em1[em1[]a.c]a)dodm()ood2ccn./
ed9[]a1[]a-/
em-/
em()dm()dmd0od0ooood0oon.codecn1[]a0/
[dm(5ccn.cd0ccn1ccn.[]d4ooood7ocn3
```

**UPDATE 3:**
Taps without delay:

```
[
code]c
ommand(0.0)/
[code]command(0.0)/
[
code]c
ommand(0.0)/
[code]command(0.0)/
[
code]c
ommand(0.0)/
[code]command(0.0)/
```

**UPDATE 4:**

```
[code]command(0.0)/
[code]command(0.0)/
[code]command(0.0)/
[code]command(0.0)/
[code]command(0.0)/
[code]command(0.01)/
[code]command(0.07)/
[code]command(0.15)/
[code]command(0.23)/
[code]command(0.29)/
[code]command(0.33)/
[code]command(0.37)/
[code]command(0.41)/
[co(0.44)/
[code]commandmmand(0.51)/
[code]code]command(0.6)/
[cod0.63)/
[cod0.65)/
[code]command(0.66)67)/
[code]command(0.68)/
2)/
```

Comment: "And then I see something like:" - is this seen on the receive side?  If so then include the Arduino receive side code.  The `onTouchEvent` is on the UI thread and the BT outputstream is a blocking write leading me to believe it is not on the send side - so I would be interested in the receive side.  (Note given the outputstream write is blocking you may end up with issues on your Android UI side - but I'm assuming that is not an issue right now.)

Comment: Hey.
I don't think that the problem on the receive side.
Receive side just receive any chars/byte that I send to it, and make a message/String. When the input is empty, or and symbol is "/", its printing a message on a display and clear this string.
Anyway, I put the code under the original message. You can take a look.
Thanks.

Comment: Buuut... maybe you right. Maybe the receive side. I put this delay(5) for some reason.

Comment: Now I feel that I need to... match a speed of transmit and receive... maybe. But don't get what exactly.

Comment: The logic in the `else` part (which I interpret as "nothing available so print what I've got so far") is wrong.  It prints what you have so far but then clears the message.  More chars come in (not yet the '/') and you print what that was (starting at (0,0)) and display that - which is just the last received characters.  I recommend commenting out the `serialMessage = "";` in the "else" part to leave the accumulated message in tact.  (may not be the only problem but try it).

Comment: Yep, I also got this) and I try to comment out this lines and leave only condition when "/" points to print the message. But, it looks like this is not only the problem. Now I receive lines like this: "[code]command(-(-1.e]command(-1.0)/" It looks like connection just looses the data while transmitting...

Comment: Anyway, thank you. I think, maybe it is a normal behaviour for BT, to lose data partially...

Comment: I think the `Serial` object has an `overflow` call so keep checking that on receive.  Also I'd add a counter to the Android side - I suspect you are getting _many_ move events.  From what I read the Arduino has a 64-byte serial buffer.  Good luck.

Comment: Hmmm... it transmit data very good when my finger is freezing in a place... (transmitting many and many lines)... but ruining in chaos only when I move the finger!!... =)

Comment: Look at UPDATE 4.

Comment: Any ideas how to limit output stream?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It was overflowed serial.
I solve this issue in two steps.
First, I decrease delay for char reading on the arduino side from 5 to 1.
Second, I send a message/command only 10 times per second.
There is a code that makes this:

```
public void send(String string) {
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeSend) > 100) {
                byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();
                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(bytes);
                } catch (IOException e) { }

                lastTimeSend = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
```